# How to disable public ip in a predefined template for a dataflow job launch

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to deploy a dataflow job using google's predefined template using python api

I do not want my dataflow compute instance to have a public ip, so I use something like this:

```
GCSPATH="gs://dataflow-templates/latest/Cloud_PubSub_to_GCS_Text"
BODY = {
    "jobName": "{jobname}".format(jobname=JOBNAME),
    "parameters": {
        "inputTopic" : "projects/{project}/topics/{topic}".format(project=PROJECT, topic=TOPIC),
        "outputDirectory": "gs://{bucket}/pubsub-backup-v2/{topic}/".format(bucket=BUCKET, topic=TOPIC),
        "outputFilenamePrefix": "{topic}-".format(topic=TOPIC),
        "outputFilenameSuffix": ".txt"
     },
     "environment": {
        "machineType": "n1-standard-1",
        "usePublicIps": False,
        "subnetwork": SUBNETWORK,
     }
}

request = service.projects().templates().launch(projectId=PROJECT, gcsPath=GCSPATH, body=BODY)
response = request.execute()
```

but I get this error:

```
raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/ABC/templates:launch?alt=json&gcsPath=gs%3A%2F%2Fdataflow-templates%2Flatest%2FCloud_PubSub_to_GCS_Text returned "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "use_public_ips" at 'launch_parameters.environment': Cannot find field.">
```

If I remove the usePublicIps, it goes through, but my compute instance gets deployed with public ip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one way to make this work

1. Clone [Google Defined Templates](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/)
2. Run the template with custom parameters

```
mvn compile exec:java \
 -Dexec.mainClass=com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.PubsubToText \
 -Dexec.cleanupDaemonThreads=false \
 -Dexec.args=" \
 --project=${PROJECT_ID} \
 --stagingLocation=gs://${BUCKET}/dataflow/pipelines/${PIPELINE_FOLDER}/staging \
 --tempLocation=gs://${BUCKET}/dataflow/pipelines/${PIPELINE_FOLDER}/temp \
 --runner=DataflowRunner \
 --windowDuration=2m \
 --numShards=1 \
 --inputTopic=projects/${PROJECT_ID}/topics/$TOPIC \
 --outputDirectory=gs://${BUCKET}/temp/ \
 --outputFilenamePrefix=windowed-file \
 --outputFilenameSuffix=.txt \
 --workerMachineType=n1-standard-1 \
 --subnetwork=${SUBNET} \
 --usePublicIps=false"
```

Comment: As two days have passed, could you accept your answer? It will make it more visible and help someone with the same issue as you find the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are using the json from [projects.locations.templates.create](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.locations.templates/create)
The environment block [documented here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/RuntimeEnvironment) needs to follow

```
"environment": {
    "machineType": "n1-standard-1",
    "ipConfiguration": "WORKER_IP_PRIVATE",
    "subnetwork": SUBNETWORK // sample: regions/${REGION}/subnetworks/${SUBNET}
}
```

The value for ipConfiguration is an enum documented at [Job.WorkerIPAddressConfiguration](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.jobs#Job.WorkerIPAddressConfiguration)

Answer (score 2):

The parameter **usePublicIps** cannot be overriden in runtime. You need to send this parameter with value false into Dataflow Template generation command.

```
mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=class -Dexec.args="--project=$PROJECT \
--runner=DataflowRunner --stagingLocation=bucket --templateLocation=bucket \
--usePublicIps=false"
```

It will add an entry **ipConfiguration** on template's JSON indicating that workers needs only with Private IP.

The links are printscreens of template JSON with and without ipConfiguration entry.

[Template with usePublicIps=false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0yEY.png)

[Template without usePublicIps=false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HfdX.png)

Answer (score 1):

By reading the docs for [Specifying your Network and Subnetwork](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-networks) on Dataflow I see that [python](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-networks#public_ip_parameter) uses `use_public_ips=false` insted of `usePublicIps=false` which is used by Java. Try changing that parameter.

Also, keep in mind that:

> When you turn off public IP addresses, the Cloud Dataflow pipeline can
>   access resources only in the following places:
>
> - another instance in the same VPC network
> - a Shared VPC network
> - a network with VPC Network Peering enabled

Comment: Tried use_public_ips=false too, same error. Note that whether I say usePublicIps or use_public_ips, the error message always flags use_public_ips.

from the document on [environment](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/RuntimeEnvironment), I don't see a way to disable public ips using rest apis

Comment: Actually the answer seems to be [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-networks)

`The public IPs parameter requires the Beam SDK for Python. The Cloud Dataflow SDK for Python does not support this parameter. To turn off public IPs:

Follow the Apache Beam pipeline dependencies instructions to stage all Python package dependencies.`

Answer (score 0):

Besides all the other methods mentioned so far, `gcloud dataflow jobs run` and `gcloud dataflow flex-template run` define the optional flag `--disable-public-ips`.